# Auto power switching between USB and a range of Lipos (1S-3S)

Tags: voltage-regulator, lipo, ldo, usb-pd

I'm designing a circuit used in a portable device. I want the option of powering the device over USB or from a range of different Lipo batteries (1S-3S).

I want the circuit to auto negotiate between each power source so that if the USB is plugged in, the Lipo input is cut off; and if the USB is out, then the Lipo input is on.

Below is my initial circuit that has taken inspiration from the Feather M4 although I'm aware that in that circuit only a 1S battery is used.

Would the circuit below work? Any recommendations/improvements?

[image: Current Circuit]

Comment: No, that only works for 1S. With 2S or more the MOSFET will always be conducting through the body diode.

Comment: And the other issue is that with 13V going into U1, you're wasting 3W in heat for every 1W of power your device consumes.